# WCF JSON Deserialize isn't working for only one variable

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON object sent to my WCF service but I am running into an issue I can't seem to solve. Only one of my variables in the JSON payload is being deserialized while the other is constantly `null`. I'm not sure why this is and I can't get it to properly deserialize both variables.

I have the following:

JSON/Request as sent via Postman:

```
POST /work/execute HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost

[{"id": "1234", "quantity": "3"}, {"id": "1234567", "quantity": "1"}]
```

WCF:

```cs
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
           UriTemplate = "work/execute")]
WorkResponse DoWork(Stream str)
{
    StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(str);
    string body = rdr.ReadToEnd();
    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<WorkRequest> reqList = ser.Deserialize<List<WorkRequest>>(body);

    return new WorkResponse() { Input = reqList };
}

[DataContract]
public class WorkRequest
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0, Name = "id")]
    public string ID;

    [DataMember(Order = 1, Name = "quantity")]
    public string Quantity;
}
```

The `JavaScriptSerializer` is able to get both `WorkRequest` objects, but once it's done deserializing the value of `ID` is `null` for both while `Quantity` properly reflects the values passed in. What am I missing?

Comment: Just a guess, but casing? It could be that Quantity works but QUantity won't, in which case you should change ID to Id.

Comment: I'm guessing that's it because you are using the `JavaScriptSerializer` and not the `DataContractSerializer`, which the `Name` property probably won't affect.

Comment: @moarboilerplate If the usage of `JavaScriptSerializer` is the culprit, then why does `Quantity` work? I'll using DataContractSerializer tomorrow; I only used `JavaScriptSerializer` as the examples I've found have all used that instead.

Comment: My guess is that Quantity works with quantity because it will try to do the translation ignoring the casing of the first letter, but everything else has to match. Try changing ID to Id and see if that works. If it doesn't, then instead of futzing around with the `DataContractJsonSerializer`, use Json.NET, as it is a much more robust solution and it is what Web API uses for its serialization as well.

Comment: @moarboilerplate I have tried this with Newtonsoft already and have the exact same problem :(

Comment: @moarboilerplate Changing ID to Id worked! I'm not sure why it serializes out correctly (using the `Name =` attribute) but fails during deserialization. If you answer the question I'll mark it as the answer.